# Puppeteer: How to write XPath for button in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

```js
var eleLoginButton = await page.waitForXPath("//input[@class='._ant-btn._ant-btn-primary']")
await eleLoginButton.click()
```

My Code is not getting Excuted if I have written it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need dot for class in XPath. Try this:

```js
var eleLoginButton = await page.waitForXPath("//input[@class='_ant-btn _ant-btn-primary']");
await eleLoginButton.click();
```